# Can i define functions in a loop statement?

Tags: javascript, function, loops, for-loop, call

I use code like the below in javascript. Is it wrong?

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++){

function somefunction(){
/*function code here*/
}

somefunction();//call that function inside the loop
}//end of for loop
```

I think i wrote a code using this and i messed up everything.

Comment: First question: Why do you need to define it **inside** of the loop? Also, were you trying to access it outside of the loop?

Comment: I'm not sure, but using an anonymous function (`var someFunction=function(){/*function code here*/}`) should work

Comment: You can, but *why* you want to do it? Is your _messed up_ stuff that the value of `i` is unexpected to you?

Comment: According to the specification, function **declarations** can't be put inside a loop or conditional statement. Browsers may still tolerate it but it could lead to unexpected behavior. That's because function declarations are *hoisted*. Using a function **expression** instead should be no problem.

Comment: It's not permitted in "strict" mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions and variables in JavaScript are scoped to the nearest *function*, not the nearest *block* (`{ ... }`).

So you cannot define *different* functions or variables each time around the loop, because you are overwriting the same name in the same scope.

As such, it would be a bad idea to put such a declaration inside the loop, whether or not the standards or implementations allowed you to do so, because it would serve only to mislead anyone reading the code (most likely yourself!).

You can create an *anonymous* function inside the loop, but without more context, I can't really give an example of how that would help you.

Comment: This is true, but only because browsers have extended the language (in not always compatible ways). The practice is not allowed in "strict" mode.

Comment: @Pointy To what are you referring? I only mention that you *can't* define two functions with the same name (regardless of browser or strictness), and that you *can* create an anonymous function (regardless of browser or strictness).

Comment: @Pointy I've added a sentence clarifying that I see the legality of the syntax as irrelevant, since the practice would be wrong anyway.

Comment: Yes your answer is fine :) I just added the comment about "strict" mode for completeness.